# Banach's theorem

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, fixed-point-theorems

as of today I've been studying metric spaces and more specifically I have been busy with Banach's theorem. I was thinking about the importance of every condition in Banach's theorem. So for example the completeness of the metric space. Image we have a metric space which isn't complete but we do have a function which is a strict contraction. What I mean by this is that
$$\forall x,y \in X: \exists c \in [0,1[: d(f(x),f(y)) \leq cd(x,y)$$
does every such strict contraction always have a fixed point or are there strict contraction which don't have any fixed points? I have looked at this question [Showing a contraction without a fixed point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/366035/showing-a-contraction-without-a-fixed-point)
but in this counterexample in the first answer only a contraction, so not a strict contraction is given. Does anyone have a tip to find a counterexample or a proof that every strict contraction have a fixed point? Any help would be greatly appreciated :))

Comment: The fixed point theorem (for a complete metric space) tells you that the fixed point is unique. Try to think of simple thing you can do to modify a complete metric space so that it is no longer complete -- i.e. that there are Cauchy sequences whose limit no longer exists. If you think through the proof of the Banach fixed point theorem, this will also tell you how to make a (non-complete) metric space with a contraction which does not have a fixed point.

Comment: What about $f:\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ with $f(x)=\frac x2$?

Comment: @FShrike Yes, but I have edited my comment.

Comment: Now that works : )

Comment: @krm2233 Maybe by taking a convegent sequence and removing its limit such that it is still a gauchy sequence but not a convergent sequence anymore?

Comment: @lukiluk That works. It's what "another user" did in their example

Comment: @AnotherUser Thank you very much. Is it true that $\mathbb{R} \backslash \{0\}$ isn't complete since for example the sequence $x_n = 1/n$ isn't convergent but still is gauchy?

Comment: Yes. More generally, no non-closed subspace of a metric space can be complete. (And it's "Cauchy", not "gauchy".)

Comment: If $X$ is a complete metric space and you remove from it a point $p$ which is not isolated (which just means that there is a sequence in $Y=X\backslash\{p\}$ which tends to $p$) then $Y$ is not complete: By assumption it contains a sequence $(x_n)$ which converges (in $X$) to $p$, thus it is a Cauchy sequence in $Y$. But if it converged to $q \in Y$, then as $Y\subseteq X$, the sequence would converge to $q\in X$, contradicting our assumption that it converged to $p$.